# Definition derivative of function f

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\text{Compute by definition derivative of function f in point } x_0,\text{ where}$$

$$ f(x)=\frac{4}{1+x^2}-\tan x, \quad x_0=\frac{\pi}{4} $$

I would be very grace for help with solving this example, because I don't know what's going on with this "counting  by definition".

Comment: Perhaps this is a typo, and "Count" was really supposed to be "Compute"?

Comment: phone dictionary, ofc It is ;p

Comment: So you know the definition of the derivative, right? The limit of a difference quotient? That's what it's referring to. $$f'(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a differential quotient $$\frac{f(x)-f\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)}{x-\dfrac{\pi}{4}}$$ and find its limit as $x\to\dfrac{\pi}{4}$. That's it.